# how to know if a page belongs to a PCI BAR

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I just wanted to know if a memory page of a PCIe BAR has something that distinguish it from any other page in the system ... ? maybe some bits in the flag ? i'm thinking of the "PG_reserved " bit.

thanks

I'll try to improve the problem explanation:

I memory-mapped the BAR0 of a PCI board into user space. Then I need the support of kernel to have the memory pages in a list which i used in other kernel functions. I managed this with the VMA flags (VM_IO).

When the user close all the stuff (and he could potentially have a lot of different pages, some are "normal" memory and some are mmio area that should not be released) I need to know which pages must stay there, but i cannot access the VMAs flags this time for many reasons... mainly because I can't modify the function prototype, and the function takes as argument just the pages list and not the associated addresses.

So I need the "best practice" to discriminate "normal" memory pages from the mmio-area pages.

In this moment i'm using the pfn_valid() function because i noticed that the mmio-area pages have a pfn "not valid", but i don't know if this is correct.

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: I tried to add information...

Comment: The obvious answer is to modify the function prototype. Anyway, while relying on side effects of the page mapping is possible, it might break in future kernel versions; at least double-check for this condition when you're mapping the pages.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not writing the driver, I'm hacking an existing one, which is not totally open source, so I can't change the function calls (which are unfortunately in the closed part).

But I'm sorry, I didn't understand what "condition" you refer... pfn_valid?

Comment: Whatever condition you're using. But why can't you get the closed-source part changed? Aren't you paying for support?